# Use FindNoCase to find url string

Tags: coldfusion

I've search around and find some valuable info. about FindNoCase but I have not yet found the answer to this specific question.

I'm using FindNoCase to find "/us/" in the url and then process some code. This works fine for one country site.

```
<cfif FindNoCase("/us/",#cgi.SCRIPT_NAME#)>
Process some code here.
</cfif>
```

My question is: Is there a way to find the piece of the url, "/xx/", for multiple country sites and process the same code between the cfif tags? For example "/us/", "/ca/", "/mx/", etc.

Hopes this makes sense.

Comment: yea, sure, strip that portion of the url into a variable, then use it in a switch case, or in a db query, etc.

Answer (score 3):

If searching for multiple different codes among a string, I'd use `REFindNoCase`. Make a regex like so `(/us/)|(/ca/)` which would look for `/us/` or `/ca/` and per the documentation (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7e99.html) you can return the sub-expressions and reference them.

No looping required.

`REFindNoCase("(/us/)|(/ca/)", URL, 1, true)`

To reference the strings you would do:

```
<cfset URL = 'domaim.com/page/us/' />
<cfset match = REFindNoCase("(/us/)|(/ca/)", URL, 1, true) />
<cfif arrayLen(match) GT 0>
    <cfset value = Mid(URL,match.pos[1],match.len[1]) />
    <cfswitch expression="#value#">
        <cfcase value="/us/">
            <!--- Do something for US match --->
        </cfcase>
        <cfcase value="/ca/">
            <!--- Do something for CA match --->
        </cfcase>
        <!--- ETC --->
    </cfswitch>
<cfelse>
    <!--- Do something if no match found --->
</cfif>
```

In this case, value would equal `/us/`. Or it should anyway. I'm writing all of this here and not actually testing on my server. You'd have to adjust this if you want to cover multiple matches in a string.

Comment: You could also use a list of country codes, rather than grouping each one ie `"/(us|ca|es|gb)/"`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to process the SAME code for several countries, if detected in the URL. You could just create a database of country codes you want to process a certain way (CountryTableXYZ), query it, then loop through that query so it'll search the URL for each entry you have in the table.

```
<cfloop query="CountryQuery">
<cfif FindNoCase("#countryCode#",#cgi.SCRIPT_NAME#)>
Process some code here.
</cfif>
</cfloop>
```

At least that's how I interpret it. If I'm not correct please let me know or clarify your initial post.